# Django: Duplicate rows from primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following table

```
id       val  
--------------
1        abc  
2        xyz  
3        abc  
4        abc
```

Given the primary key(id) I need to be able to get all the rows with the same val as the row with the primary key.

Currently I have the following django code:

```
Table.objects.filter(val = Table.objects.get(id=1).val)
```

But this makes two queries to the database. I want to reduce this to a single database call. Is this possible in Django.

Comment: What's wrong with your approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
Table.objects.extra(where=['val=(select val from app_table where id=1)'])
```

This will result into single query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    app_table 
WHERE 
    val=(SELECT val FROM app_table WHERE id=1)
```